# ¿Cómo trabajar un menú con clases, objetos y arrays char?

Tags: c++, array, poo, ascii, char

Escriba un programa en C++ que permita ingresar los datos de un estudiante: nombre y apellido, código (de 8 dígitos), usuario  (será el apellido del estudiante) y clave (una combinación de letras minúsculas, mayúsculas y dígitos), a través de un menú.

El programa debe verificar si el código tiene 8 dígitos, y si la clave tiene las condiciones señaladas. De lo contrario se pedirá ingresar el dato (pero solo ese dato) de nuevo. Solo se tienen 3 opciones para ingresar los datos correctamente. Luego de ingresar los datos (input), el programa preguntará si se quiere modificar algún dato.

Se abrirá entonces el menú de nuevo para que el usuario escoja un dato para modificar, o ningún dato para salir.

Declare un tipo o clase que represente una clave, consistente en una cadena de n caracteres. El tamaño n lo ingresa el usuario (input). Defina la estructura de esta nueva clase (atributos y métodos).

Los caracteres de la clave deben ser aleatorios, pero deben ser mayúsculas, minúsculas o dígitos (entre 0 y 9). Aquí puede usar constructores.

Ahora defina un método para convertir la clave a una secuencia de binarios. Si la letra es A (o a) el dígito binario será 1, si es B (o b), será 0, si es C (o c) será 1, y así sucesivamente, en forma intercalada. Si el dígito es par, será 0, si es impar, será 1.

*Por ejemplo, si la clave generada es aB2cBa1, la clave binaria generada será 1001011.*

Ahora defina un método para encontrar una llave que corresponda a la clave creada. Esta tendrá el doble de dígitos que la clave original, y contendrá dos 1s si la clave tiene un 0, o dos 0s si la clave tiene un 1. Para el ejemplo anterior, la llave será 00111100110000.

El ultimo dígito de la llave, es 0 si la cantidad de caracteres original es par o 1 si la cantidad de caracteres es impar.

*La llave final en el ejemplo será 00111100110001, porque la clave original tiene n=7 caracteres.*

Al culminar, el código debe imprimir los datos del estudiante, la cadena de caracteres, la clave y llave generadas. Utilice la función rand() para generar números random. Recuerde que debe inicializar la funcion rand() con srand(). Además, cada carácter tiene un entero asociado (código ASCII). Lo pueden obtener haciendo una conversión a entero (typecasting).

**Decidí trabajar el menú de la forma común (switch); sin embargo, me encontré con la dificultad de evaluar un array char para la clave. Este es el código:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int opcion, cambio, codigo;
string nombre, apellido, usuario, num_codigo, clave;

int main() {
  while (1==1){
    cout << " Hola, querido estudiante.\n Elija una opción para completar sus datos:\n ----------------------- \n  1.Nombre y apellido \n  2.Código estudiantil \n  3.Usuario \n  4.Clave \n  5.Modificar algún dato \n  6.Salir \n ----------------------- \n" << endl;
    cin >> opcion; cout << endl;
  switch(opcion) {
    case 1:
      cout << "||Nombre y apellido||\n Ingresa tu nombre: ";
      cin >> nombre;
      cout << " Ingresa tu apellido: ";
      cin >> apellido; cout << endl;
      break;
    case 2:
      do {
        cout << "||Código estudiantil||\n Ingresa tu código [8 dígitos]: ";
        cin >> codigo; cout << endl;
        string num_codigo(to_string(codigo));
        break;
      } while ((num_codigo.length()>8) or (num_codigo.length()<8));
      break;
    case 3:
      do {
        cout << "||Usuario||\n Ingresa tu usuario [debe ser igual a tu apellido]: ";
        cin >> usuario; cout << endl;
      } while (usuario != apellido);
      break;
    case 4:
      cout << "||Clave||\n Ingresa tu clave [debe contener letras minúsculas, mayúsculas y dígitos]: ";
      cin >> clave; cout << endl;
      break;
    case 5:
      cout << " Oh!, te ayudaré a modificar tus datos.\n Elige una de las opciones:\n......................\n  01.Cambiar nombre y apellido\n  02.Cambiar código\n  03.Cambiar usuario\n  04.Cambiar clave\n  05.No modificar datos\n......................\n";
      cin >> cambio; cout << endl;
      if (cambio==01) cout << "|Introduce tu nombre: "; cin >> nombre; cout << endl; cout << "|Introduce tu apellido: "; cin >> apellido; cout << endl; break;
      if (cambio==02) cout << "|Introduce tu código: "; cin >> codigo; cout << endl; break;
      if (cambio==03) cout << "|Introduce tu usuario: "; cin >> usuario; cout << endl; break;
      if (cambio==04) cout << "|Introduce tu clave: "; cin >> clave; cout << endl; break;
      if (cambio==05) cout << "Genial! Ahora volverás al menú." << endl; break;
      break;
    case 6:
      cout << " Gracias por tu registro.\n A continuación te mostraré tus datos: " << endl; cout << "/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/" << endl; cout << " Nombre y apellido: " << nombre << " " << apellido << "." << endl; cout << " Código estudiantil: " << codigo << "." << endl; cout << " Usuario: " << usuario << "." << endl; cout << " Clave: " << clave << "." << endl; cout << "/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/" << endl;
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      break;
    default:
      cout << " Ups!, la opción no es válida.\n Solo debe ingresar números del 1 al 6.\n" << endl;
      break;
  }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Me sería de mucha ayuda si me explicasen cómo estructurarlo con clases y objetos. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: La clave debe estar autogenerada. No debe ser introducida por el usuario

Comment: ¿Y cuál sería un método para evaluarla?

Comment: No tienes que evaluarla. Te dice que la contraseña es aleatoria y cual es el conjunto de caracteres que puede tener. En ningun sitio te dice que tenga que tener un mínimo/máximo de X números o caracteres en minúsculas o mayúsculas

Comment: Simplemente tienes que diseñar un algoritmo que, dada un número, te devuelva una clave de dicha longitud que contenga únicamente letras mayúsculas, minúsculas y números

Comment: Luego creas una clase que genere dicha clave y la encapsule, eso es lo que te están pidiendo en el ejercicio